# Anonymous domain registration?

Tags: domains, whois

For privacy reasons, I'd like to hide my personal information **including my name** in the WHOIS registry, while registering with OVH.

In OVH's [OwO Terms of Use](https://www.ovh.co.uk/g2137.whois_-_activation_de_owo), the following information is stated :

```
An individual:
All of the contact's details can be hidden (apart from their full name).
```

However, I already saw multiple OVH-registered anonymous domain names.

For example, here's an extract of "synonymo.fr"'s WHOIS, following [OVH's website](https://www.ovh.com/fr/cgi-bin/tools/check_whois.pl):

```
registrar:   OVH
type:        Isp Option 1
address:     2 Rue Kellermann
address:     ROUBAIX
country:     FR
phone:       +33 8 99 70 17 61
fax-no:      +33 3 20 20 09 58
e-mail:      support@ovh.net
website:     http://www.ovh.com
anonymous:   NO
registered:  21/10/1999
source:      FRNIC

nic-hdl:     ANO00-FRNIC
type:        PERSON
contact:     Ano Nymous
remarks:     -------------- WARNING --------------
remarks:     While the registrar knows him/her,
remarks:     this person chose to restrict access
remarks:     to his/her personal data. So PLEASE,
remarks:     don't send emails to Ano Nymous. This
remarks:     address is bogus and there is no hope
remarks:     of a reply.
remarks:     -------------- WARNING --------------
registrar:   OVH
changed:     11/01/2009 anonymous@anonymous
anonymous:   YES
obsoleted:   NO
source:      FRNIC
```

As you can see, it's stated as anonymous despite being registered with OVH. How is it possible?

Thanks in advance (and sorry if my English is awful).

**PS:** Here I'm only talking about ".fr" domain names. I suppose it may be important to mention it; I don't know if the same rules are applied across all the domains.

Comment: So you mean the original domain owner name should be there for above case as per their TOS?

Answer (score 2):

In .FR, by default, all owner data is hidden from whois information. This is in fact a frequent case among ccTLDs, a rare case (at the registry level) on gTLDs. And on top of that, various registrars provide privacy/proxy services to change the data displayed through whois.

As the whois says, obviously the registrar has the correct data (at least what you have provided and you are in breach of contract if you provided false data), and the registry (AFNIC) has it too, but per French/European laws it does not disclose this owner data through public queries.

See article 8.4 in [AFNIC .FR rules](https://www.afnic.fr/medias/documents/Cadre_legal/Charte_de_Nommage_Afnic_du_12122016_VF.pdf)

PS: both your registrar and the registry support team should be able to answer your question regarded to .FR domain names. You pay them for the service, so you should not be afraid to ask them for help.